# ERROR_ALREADY_REQUESTING_PERMISSIONS on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

I create an android app with flutter, I create permission request at the first time when app is run, so when user click deny and then click login button, permission requested again. I got this error

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(ERROR_ALREADY_REQUESTING_PERMISSIONS, A request for permissions is already running, please wait for it to finish before doing another request (note that you can request multiple permissions at the same time)., null))
```

this is my code

```
@override
  void initState() {
    this.setSharedPreferences();
    PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.location).then(_checkPermission);
  }

void _checkPermission(PermissionStatus status){
    if(status == PermissionStatus.unknown || status == PermissionStatus.denied){
      _askPermission();
    }
  }

void _askPermission() async{
    await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.location]);
  }

void onLogin() async {
   PermissionStatus locationPermission = await PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.location);
   if(locationPermission == PermissionStatus.denied || locationPermission == PermissionStatus.unknown){
        _askPermission();
   }else{
     // user available to login
   }
}
```

How to handle this? thanks for your answer

Comment: how did you fix these issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The thing is when it checks for permission it returns null instead of any of the Permission status, which results in a exception. It could possibly a bug multiple people have filled issues related to Location permission.

https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-geolocator/issues/172

https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-geolocator/issues/

https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/issues

```
void getPermissionStatus() async {
        PermissionStatus permission = await PermissionHandler()
            .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.storage);
        if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        } // ideally you should specify another condition if permissions is denied
else if (permission == PermissionStatus.denied ||
            permission == PermissionStatus.disabled ||
            permission == PermissionStatus.restricted) {
          await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);
          getPermissionStatus();
        }
      }
```

I don't  think there is problem with your code anyway you can use recursion instead of creating two separate functions.

Comment: @NdeemSiddhique While getting location permission if Permission status is disabled means App has location permission but the location of that device is of then Is there any way to guide user for turn on location of that device.

Comment: This is a very dangerous solution! it can easily result in an infinity loop, which would crash the app.

Comment: Not an infinite loop exactly but it won't let the user get past until it allows the permission. Depends on usercase but I agree it's not idle. I'll update it.

Comment: Can some one please write this same code with latest version of the  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing `ERROR_ALREADY_REQUESTING_PERMISSIONS` but it was caused by something different for me. I thought I'd post it in case someone else is dealing with the same thing.

Make sure your version of the OP's `_askPermission()` is only being called once. I was requesting permissions within a listener but didn't realize my listener was being called more than once in quick succession.

Comment: Same. I had another tab calling my getLocation() method if the current position was null when it loaded the second tab. yikes!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using the updated version of permission_handler:

```
Future<void> permission() async {
  if (await Permission.storage.isDenied) {
    await Permission.storage.request();
  }
  if (await Permission.location.isDenied) {
    await Permission.location.request();
  }
```

From this way, you can ask for multiple permissions at once...

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (this was for contact permission, but should work for others too)

```
PermissionStatus permissionStatus; // note do not use PermissionStatus? permissionStatus;

while (true) {
    try {
       permissionStatus = await permission. Request();
       break; 
    } catch (e) {
       await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {});
    }
}
```