# flutter geolocator returned Unhandled Exception

Tags: flutter, geolocation

```
void _getCurrentLocation() async {

    final position = await Geolocator()
                          .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);

   

  }
```

this is my info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs access to location when open.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to location when open and in the background.</string>
```

The above code snippet returns the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ERROR_MISSING_PROPERTYKEY, To
> use location in iOS8 you need to define
> NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in the app bundle's Info.plist
> file, null)

however I already added it to my info.plist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR\_ALREADY\_REQUESTING\_PERMISSIONS on flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56069917/error-already-requesting-permissions-on-flutter)

Comment: I tried some of them by it doesn't help